# How to use a SELECT query inside an ON CLAUSE in a LEFT OUTER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

I need to retrieve data from several tables. For now I am getting maximum of them from

```
     SELECT disc.id, 
        users.user_login as 'last_active_user',
        disc.discussion_sub,
        list.todo_list_title, 
        todo.todo_title,
        count(comments.comment),   
        MAX(CAST(comments.comment_posted AS CHAR))
    FROM abc_discussions as disc
    LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_todo_list as list
    ON disc.comment_table_type = 'todo_list' AND disc.comment_table_id = list.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_todo as todo
    ON disc.comment_table_type = 'todo_item' AND disc.comment_table_id = todo.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_users as users
    ON users.user_id = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_comments as comments
    ON disc.id = comments.discussion_id
    GROUP BY disc.id
```

where `$last_comment_by->user_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT user_id FROM abc_comments ORDER BY comment_posted DESC LIMIT 1" )->user_id;`

Is there any way to make it a single query?

I tried

```
SELECT a.id , 
a.discussion_sub,
b.todo_list_title,
c.todo_title,
ANY_VALUE(q.user_login) as 'last_active_user',
count(comment),
MAX(comment_posted)
FROM abc_discussions a 
LEFT JOIN abc_todo_list b
ON a.comment_table_type = 'todo_list' AND a.comment_table_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN abc_todo c 
ON a.comment_table_type = 'todo_item' AND a.comment_table_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT x.user_id as user_id, y.discussion_id as discussion_id 
    FROM abc_users x
    LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_comments y
    ON x.user_id = y.user_id ) d
 ON d.discussion_id = a.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN abc_users q 
ON q.user_id = d.user_id
 LEFT JOIN abc_comments e 
ON a.id = e.discussion_id 
GROUP BY a.id
```

But getting wrong result for user_login and comment count .

Comment: I suggest you add aliases to the tables and use them throughout the query. Example: `FROM  abc_discussions as d LEFT JOIN abc_todo_list tl ON d.... = tl....` It makes it easier to understand where things origins from.

Comment: @Lennart thank you for your suggestion . Is there a possible solution to what I want to achieve ?

Comment: @Lennart I have tried to implement your idea if I still can make it better please let me know.

Comment: It's not a solution per se, but it will make it easier to understand your query hence easier to suggest a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Lennart I do understand it and I implemented to make it simple and want to know if there is a possible solution to this ?

Comment: If you don't need `LEFT`, remove it.

Comment: What datatype is `comment_posted`?  If it is numeric, won't you get the wrong answer if using string comparisions?  If it is a string, why do the `CAST`?

Comment: `JOINs` (including `LEFT JOIN`) inflate the number of rows, then `COUNT` comes up with the wrong answer.

Comment: Please add aliases to the column names so I can figure out what is going on.  For example, I need to know what table contains `comment`.  Then, maybe I can give you a simple answer to your question.

Comment: @RickJames thank you so much for your reply comment_posted is datetime type , and for rest I am editing my question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"last_active_user" sounds like

```
( SELECT user_login FROM users WHERE ... ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

count(comments.comment) sounds like

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM abc_comments WHERE ... )
```

That is, get rid of the joins and replace the aggregate values by subqueries as above.

`JOIN` explodes the number of rows, then

- You need a `GROUP BY` to get it back in check
- `COUNT` counts too big a number
- Items (such as `user_login`) that are not in `GROUP BY` end up with unpredictable values.
- Etc.

(Yes, `MAX(comment_posted)`, is the same as, but simpler than, `MAX(CAST(comments.comment_posted AS CHAR))`.)

Answer (score 0):

How about somethig like this :

```
SELECT a.id
         , user_login as 'last_active_user'
         , discussion_sub
         , todo_list_title
         , todo_title
         , count(comment)
         , MAX(CAST(comment_posted AS CHAR)) 
    FROM abc_discussions a
    LEFT JOIN abc_todo_list b ON comment_table_type = 'todo_list' AND comment_table_id = b.id 
    LEFT JOIN abc_todo c ON comment_table_type = 'todo_item' AND comment_table_id = c.id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        ( SELECT x.*
          FROM abc_users x
          INNER JOIN abc_comments y ON y.user_id = x.id) d on 1 = 1 -- or however you wish to join this to the rest of your query
    LEFT JOIN abc_comments e ON a.id = e.discussion_id 
    GROUP BY a.id
         , user_login
         , discussion_sub
         , todo_list_title
         , todo_title
```

Comment: I tried your answer and getting got error unknown column d.id, can you tell me what d.id refers to ?

Comment: I've fixed the column aliases

Comment: thank you for you quick response, Now I am getting #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'd.user_login' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by  . :(

Comment: Well yes, you'd probably get that with your first query too, you have to group by all the non-aggregate columns in the select clause.
I'll adjust the select

Comment: I noticed something x.user_id = y.id is comparing comment id to user id which will return false all ways.

Comment: I tried something and got wrong result, included the query in my question, can you please check it .

Comment: just editied, try it now

Comment: Sorry for late response, I will let you know tomorrow, actually it is a wordpress plugin and I am adding few more tables to handle files, so now it is in deactivated condition and I also need to create some data to test and it is weekend, It is in bitbocket, I will install it on a demo site and test it in the morning . again thank you for your kind response  :)

Comment: we are still getting wrong ccount(comment) and MAX(CAST(comment_posted AS CHAR)).